# How to avoid the SQL Server's "rebuild statistics" when doing performance testing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, testing

I'm doing some SQL tuning these days and find one weird sql during the test:

```
SELECT StatMan([SC0],[SC1], [SB0000]) 
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [SC0],[SC1], step_direction([SC0]) over (order by NULL) AS [SB0000]  
      FROM (SELECT [tableA] AS [SC0],[tableB] AS [SC1] 
            FROM [dbo].[url] WITH (READUNCOMMITTED,SAMPLE 3.408654e+000 PERCENT) 
           ) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL_HELPER 
     ORDER BY [SC0],[SC1], [SB0000] 
    ) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL  
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Looks this is doing some "reindex" or "rebuild" some db index according to SQL Server. But my question is how can we avoid this during the long load test besides "reindex" for each tables before the testing.

And this SQL will consume 16862ms because of my table contains enough rows. And there are many *insert* action in my test.

Comment: That looks like an auto update statistics query to me. You can turn that off either for the whole database or for individual indexes but your other queries may suffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be from updating statistics.

Will updating statistics happen in a normal production environment? If so, shouldn't a load test, to reflect a production environment, update statistics as well?

To turn off the AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS option, use sp_autostats on the desired table(s) (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188775.aspx ).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm running on the performance env. This really helpful!

Comment: Thanks. Remember that, if you turn off AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS, you may want to run a manual UPDATE STATISTICS during off-peak times.

Comment: If my testing sql is for "query" only, do I have to UPDATE STATISTICS before/after the test?

Comment: A query (select only) statement should not affect the existing statistics. So, UPDATE STATISTICS should not be necessary. With modifications (INSERTS, UPDATES, DELETES), though, you should update the statistics after large changes (and ideally before queries that rely on indexes that rely on those statistics). In my experience, highly volatile tables need to have auto update stats on in production. More stable tables can be set to either update manually on a scheduled job or after a major modifications. Entirely stable tables (think system lookups) only need to be updated after modifications.

Comment: Rather than completely doing away with auto update, you should look into 2 things. One is doing an Asynchronous Update (its an option right under Auto Update Stats). The other is using trace flag 2371 to change auto updates from a fixed 20% of row delta to a sliding scale based on the number of rows in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Before changing anything, I would let it run as is, with SQL Profiler and then get Tuning Advisor to analyze results. It can find some inefficiencies in table design. Also some pretty innocent things can affect it: e.g. having "too many indexes" or using GUID as PK on a table that has more inserts than selects...

If all inefficiencies are resolved, and you still have performance hit, then yea, you can turn auto-stats off and get stats updated at off peak time. But then you must do the same on production, as person before have said.